# How to set vim to unindent when meets a empty line in Python?

Tags: python, vim

It could be useful if vim could do a unindentation automatically when I type an empty line, but it seems it is not the default behavior. This would especially useful for Python, could Vim be configured to do so?

Comment: I have tried this in the past and found the endresult very annoying. Think about it: an average indented block is about 3 lines, so __continuing__ a code block happens on average 3 times as much as __stopping__ a code block.

Comment: Vim removes indentation on an empty line when you press Enter again; try starting vim without any plugins (`vim -u NONE -N`) and source plugins one by one until you figure out which one is causing it.

Comment: There should be an indentation file for Python installed. Look for python.vim in /usr, or try [a replacement version](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974).

Comment: As an alternative, `<c-d>` in insert mode will decrease the indention level.

Comment: @Adam Backstrom, there is a python.vim installed, and the indentation works correctly for python program, only the unindenttation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some mods to my own `indent/python.vim` to enable full dedent when the third empty line is entered. You may be able to adapt this to your needs.

```
diff --git a/python.vim b/python.vim
index 0c04e81..c60c30e 100644
--- a/python.vim
+++ b/python.vim
@@ -142,8 +142,14 @@ function GetPythonIndent(lnum)
       " If not, recommend one dedent
       return indent(plnum) - &sw
     endif
-    " Otherwise, trust the user
-    return -1
+
+       " Is user trying to break out of this function?
+       if plnum < a:lnum - 2
+         return 0
+       else
+         " Otherwise, trust the user
+         return -1
+       endif
   endif

   " If the current line begins with a keyword that lines up with "try"
@@ -186,6 +192,11 @@ function GetPythonIndent(lnum)
     return plindent
   endif

+  " Double linebreaks means we're starting a new function (probably)
+  if plnum < a:lnum - 2
+       return 0
+  endif
+
   return -1

 endfunction
```